# how to insert base64 string to image src in angular

Tags: angular

in my config.ts,

```
export const imageBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAiAAA...."
```

in my conmonent.ts

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { imageBase64 } from './config'
...
  myImg: SafeUrl; 
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
     this.myImg= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageBase64 );
  }
```

in my html

```
<img [src]="myImg" alt="" />
```

unfortunately, this fail, error message `net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

then i use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` fail too,  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Please share imageBase64 value at https://jsoneditoronline.org/.

Comment: Is `imageBase64` is valid data? bcs your code is just working fine in jsfiddle https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lm9eed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts with correct base 64 data

Comment: `console.log(imageBase64)`? before sanitizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to sanitize the base64 data.
We can use string interpolation to show whatever the data we have in the form of string

```
<img src={{ imageBase64}} alt="" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot,   the base64 data was wrong lead to an error, and don't need to sanitize the base64 data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use interpolation: `src={{myImg}}`

See below jsFiddle to help out:https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use `get` property to return url

```
public get myImg(): string {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageBase64 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine. Try the demo and find where you went wrong.

```
<img [src]="imageBase64" alt="">
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzjusl